# Cannot install Ubuntu on a HP Envy 2-in-1 laptop (model 13-baXXXX)

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, hp

I have trawled though numerous posts around issues installing Ubuntu on my Hp Envy laptop. Unfortunately, seems nobody has been able to do it so far. P.S I have tried almost everything on BIOS such as disabling TPM, SecureBoot etc... but no luck. (dont wont Virtual Machine install).
Just checking again if anyone has been successful and how to do it? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Could you elaborate on the issue? Are you seeing errors? Are you able to run the installer, but Ubuntu is not installed? Does the OS install, but won't boot? With a bit more clarity, someone may be able to offer a suggestion on how to overcome the issue 

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of embarrassing as i did manage to install Ubuntu in my HPEnvy.
I tried the following and it worked:

1. Went to Windows > Intel Optane Memory Storage Apps> Enabled RPT Memory
2. Restart, then went back in Windows then disabled it
   3.Restart windows
3. Restart windows then went to BIOS

- Disbaled TPM state
- Ensure Secure Boot is disabled

5. Reboot and booted off my Ubuntu ISO image on USB

> > > > > > VOILA - Ubuntu installed successfully with no issues
> > > > > > FINALLY!!!

Comment: You should be able to enable secure boot without any issues. I also had to disable Optane, but was able to install both Kubuntu and Ubuntu Studio with secure boot. Congrats on a working system!