# I am struggling to dual boot Ubuntu 22.04 with Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi, usb-installation

I am currently running windows 10 on an HP Envy Laptop. I have partitioned 64GB of hard disk space to install Ubuntu 22.04. I can successfully access Ubuntu installation from USB and supposedly install to the partitioned disk space and it all looks good. However, once the USB is gone and I re-boot I have no way to access Ubuntu, as if it was never there. I get no grub menu. I do get an Ubuntu option in boot device options but when I select it I get a blank screen with a caret. When I go to UEFI boot order, I have no Ubuntu option.

I have disabled secure boot, fast start-up, and bitlocker drive encryption. I have tried multiple times to reinstall with the same result.

I have thoroughly followed various tutorials with no success. Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Every other system than HP, supports efibootmgr which installer/grub uses to add Ubuntu entry to UEFI boot menu & make it first in boot order. HP users have to go into UEFI settings (not UEFI boot menu) and change boot order in settings. HP - escape + F9 for UEFI boot menu, F10 for UEFI/bios settings https://askubuntu.com/questions/1332255/dual-boot-only-booting-into-windows-no-option-to-choose-between-windows-or-ubun If Optane, you may need to disable. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1455932/cannot-install-ubuntu-on-a-hp-envy-2-in-1-laptop-model-13-baxxxx

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)